# How do I convert date and time to timestamp in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and Jdf and I want to convert the date and time to timestamp, but it is always 0, I do not know why.

I want the start date and end date to be timestamped

file AdminController.php

```
public function add_incredible_offers(Request $request) 
{
    $date1=$request->get('date1');
    $date2=$request->get('date2');
    $offers_first_time=getTimestamp($date1,'first');
    $offers_last_time=getTimestamp($date2,'last');

    return $offers_first_time;
}
```

file helpers.php

[See the image here file helpers.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsALr.png)

Comment: Dont post images of code, add the code from helpers in your question. Wat dus `dd($date1)` output? Side note: why not use Carbon to convert the date?

Answer (score 3):

You're sending parameters to the function in wrong order.

change

```
$offers_first_time=getTimestamp($date1,'first'); 
$offers_last_time=getTimestamp($date2,'last');
```

to

```
 $offers_first_time=getTimestamp('first',$date1); 
 $offers_last_time=getTimestamp('last',$date2);
```

alternatively you can easily use Carbon.

```
$offers_first_time = \Carbon\Carbon::make($request->input('date1'))->timestamp;

$offers_last_time = \Carbon\Carbon::make($request->input('date1'))->timestamp;
```